# Why use Android AppCompat v7 GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a reason to use Android AppCompat v7 GridLayout instead of the old GridLayout? Does v7 GridLayout have functionality that the old one doesn't have? Are there other advantages to using v7 GridLayout?

Are there disadvantages to using v7 GridLayout? When an app uses v7 GridLayout, the app has to include another library in its dependencies. Is the additional dependency a disadvantage?

Comment: Please have a look at the https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html

Comment: Thank you. The information at that link was helpful. However, it is fairly general information and didn't answer my questions about GridLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When android api <21 ,it didn't work well.

So use it more to fit the Android version .

So we can add compile.

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
```

And sample.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f11"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

**Note**

In the `com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1`

`25.3.1` change to your own .

It had new attribute.

- app:layout_columnWeight
- app:layout_rowWeight
- app:layout_rowSpan
- app:layout_columnSpan

You can use in your code.